# CGI Python проблема с кодировкой.

Tags: python, cgi, кодировка

Добрый день.

Подскажите идеи пожалуйста, есть такая задача - CGI-приложение из веб-формы получает данные, а потом по ним заводит пользователя в Zimbra (путем вызова зимбровского бинарника). Проблема в том, что в форме есть русские символы (unquote естественно делаю), и все бы хорошо. но вот в зимбру они передаются в виде ???????. (английские - как надо)
локаль системы

> `LANG=POSIX
> LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
> LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
> LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
> LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
> LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
> LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
> LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
> LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
> LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
> LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
> LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
> LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
> LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`

Локаль sudo и пользователя zimbra - такие же. Питоновский скрипт

```
-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

В файлы пишет абсолютно прекрасно и читаемо, проблема именно в случае, когда я вызываю

```
cmd = 'sudo /opt/zimbra/bin/zmprov'
subprocess.Popen(cmd + " ca "+ string_param, shell = True)
```

Причем дело не в форме, если я укажу переменную внутри скрипта (на русском), то такая же проблема.

До этого пытался сделать скрипт на bash (не хватило функционала), но там эту проблему решил путем

```
export LANG=POSIX
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 (помоему зимбра тогда ru_RU использовала)
```

Видимо, дело упирается в этот самый LANG, но как это решить, я не могу понять. Подскажите пожалуйста, замучился уже.

Comment: string_param - это unicode?

Comment: string_param - это строка формирующаяся из передаваемого массива, выглядит примерно как "givenName Иван surName Иванов " и тд, если её вывести через print в браузер - все отлично, русские распознаются абсолютно нормально.

Answer (score 1):

```
subprocess.Popen(u"%s ca %s" % (cmd, string_param), shell = True)
```

Так пробывали надеюсь?

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 53: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: ой пардон, не то кинул.
subprocess.Popen(u"%s ca %s".encode('utf-8') % (cmd, string_param), shell = True)
точно также отображается знаками вопроса